# RabbitMQ service start failure due to bad .erlang cookie location

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

Erlang crashes on rabbitMQ service start, due to bad unable to create erlang.cookie path [Image Attached (Log File)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FAwT.png).  I need to figure out why it's adding an extra c: to the beginning of the path, and where that's defined.  Any suggestions.  I've uninstalled and deleted everything relating to rabbitMQ multiple times. include the registry items and environment variables.